# In wicket is there a way to read localized properties directly?

Tags: java, properties, internationalization, wicket-6

Among others I have these two properties with differing values in all my localized .properties files:

```
...
StateShow=true
StateLabel=State
...
```

When the user picks a country protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) is called and the following lines among others in that method work:

```
...
getSession().setLocale(locale);
...
stateLabel.setDefaultModel(new StringResourceModel("StateLabel",target.getPage(),null));
...
```

That is to say that in US it says State, in Canada it says Province, in Japan it says Prefecture, etc.  But the following line does not work:

```
...
showState       = Boolean.getBoolean(new StringResourceModel("StateShow",       target.getPage(),null).getString());
...
```

That is to say when the correct .properties file says StateShow=true showState is always false.

Is there anyway to accurately access localized properties that aren't being used as Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably not be related to Wicket but to your usage of `Boolean.getBoolean(String)` which tries to find a system property with the given name (check the javadoc).

So I would assume that your `StringResourceModel` correctly returns the value "true". Then `Boolean.getBoolean(String)` tries to find a the system property named "true" which probably doesn't exist and thus returns false.

You probably want to use `Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` instead.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb(er)